# Implementing a subshell in c

Tags: c, shell, unix, posix

I have implemented a bash like shell in c language. I support `<` `>` `>>` `;` `|` and `&`. My next task is to add a support for `(` and `)` basically a subshell. How can we implement a subshell. I can fork and put parent on wait, pass environment variables but I need to add support to commands like `(ls | sort) ; ls` (I admit that the command does not make much sense but it explains the motive)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show the code and show where you are having problems.

Comment: bash is open-source, why don't you look at how it does it?

Comment: I do not have problems, I just do not have the idea to implementth esubshell.

Comment: @Barmar: I feel like that I will get lost in the  code but that is the last option I guess

Comment: Once you fork, the child implements `ls | sort` the same way you do in the main shell.

Comment: The state of the program is same as the parent program after `fork` so I think that I have to call a `exec` family function to run it from starting but then I face the problem of passing `ls|sort` to the `exec`ed child. If I am not clear please tell me.

Comment: Why would you not pull it from the buffer the parent was using?

Comment: The buffer parent is using has `(ls | sort) ; ls` but I only need `ls | sort` in the sub shell. How do I extract this in the subshell?

Comment: What you should do is parse the entire line into some kind of tree structure. Nodes in the tree would be categorized as things like "sequential" (for `cmd1;cmd2`), "pipeline" (for `cmd1|cmd2`), and subshell (for `(cmdline)`). Execute the command line with a recursive algorithm -- when it encounters a subshell node it forks, and the child process then processes the subtree under that node.

Comment: yes it was, actually deadline over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO implement this we parse the command line and make a tree like structure. This can be done with the help of `lex` and `yacc` and as barmer suggested we can name each node as `subshell` `pipeline` `semicolon`. After parsing the whole command line pass the pointer to the whole node to the main program. To run a subshell `fork` and then reload the same  program using `execve` passing the current environment.